# append JSON values within nested arrays

Tags: jquery, html, json

Currently I am using the following code to display parts of a JSON data file:

```
$.getJSON( 
    "json.json",
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.events, function() {
            $('#listings').append("<p>" + this['eventname'] + "</p><p>" + this['eventurl'] + "</p><p>" + this['dates[startdate]'] + "</p>");
        });
    }
);
```

This is part of a locally cached and created JSON file which I'm retrieving the data from.

```
"events": [
    {
        "eventid": "4419605",
        "facebookeventid": "",
        "eventname": "Mervi"
        "dates": {
            "startdate": "20120529010000",
            "enddate": "20121231235500",
            "timezone": "EDT"
        },
        "venue": {
            "venueid": "210795",
            "name": "On
            "venueimages": {
                "large": "",
                "small": ""
            }
        },
        "eventimages": [""],
        "prices": {
            "pricelow": "$195.00",
            "pricehigh": "$195.00",
            "pricedisplay": "$195.00"
        },
        "attractionList": [
            {
                "sequence": "0",
                "artist": "",
                "artistid": "7014411",
                "billing": "1.00",
                "genre": "Seminar/Lecture",
                "links": "",
                "media": ""
            },
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "artist": "Families.",
                "artistid": "7014441",
                "billing": "0.75",
                "links": "",
                "media": ""
            },
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "artist": "Se",
                "artistid": "7014451",
                "billing": "0.75",
                "links": "",
                "media": ""
            }
        ]
    },
```

I can access the `eventname` and the following key entries to produce the values in html (which is what I'm after) but when I want to display the `venueid` value, this is inside `venue` which inside the array. And `eventimages` which has an empty array, which too is inside the main array. What would be the right syntax to display the data here? Am i using the right JSON/AJAX menthod to display complicated JSON structures like this one? Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON syntax is incorrect

Comment: You can validate your JSON string @ here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you fix a few things that are broken in your current JSON object, you can access these properties by `this.venue.venueid` (just as you can use `this.eventname` rather than `this['eventname']`).

If you for some reason prefer the stringed notation, the equivalent would be `this['venue']['venueid']` but I see no useful case for it here.

The problems in your JSON object are

- Missing comma after event name
- Unterminated string and missing comma after venue name